# @Aspect not called when using annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, aspectj

I create an annotation to make some operations as bellow:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Verify {
}
```

and an Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class VerifyAspect {
    @Before("execution(public * *(.., @Verify (*), ..))")
    public void actionBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
       System.out.println(joinPoint); // <<-------------- can't see this message
    }
}
```

and a config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class VerifyConfig {
}
```

But when I call:

```
public void method(@Verify MyObject obj){
   // do something
}
```

The Aspect not called at all. do I make any mistake in my creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html?fbclid=IwAR0FN-ulrxzncCYNwz6JCJob1OCOLJ_uqNGFmjp-oP4JV1KWBrn_20D7XiY#aop-introduction-spring-defn) : Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans) - So make sure, the method you are calling

```
public void method(@Verify MyObject obj){
   // do something
}
```

is declared inside one of the Spring Beans.

Based on the code you've shared, I created a simple demo:

Also make sure, the aspectjweaver.jar is in your dependencies

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Main Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AspecjStyleAopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AspecjStyleAopApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Configuration**

Here, make sure you provide the correct basePackages for Spring to scan for your components

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class AspectJConfig {
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Verify {
}
```

**Aspect**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class VerifyAspect {

    @Before("execution(public * *(.., @Verify (*), ..))")
    public void actionBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("THIS SHOULD BE DISPLAYED");
        System.out.println(joinPoint); // <<-------------- can't see this message
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class SampleService {

    public void method(@Verify Object obj){
        System.out.println("Passed object: " + obj);
    }
}
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
public class SampleRestController {

    private final SampleService sampleService;

    public SampleRestController(SampleService sampleService) {
        this.sampleService = sampleService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/sample")
    public String sampleRestMethod() {
        sampleService.method(5);
        return "It works";
    }
}
```

And the output from the console, when I call `http://localhost:8080/sample` endpoint:

```
THIS SHOULD BE DISPLAYED
execution(void com.example.aspecjstyleaop.SampleService.method(Object))
Passed object: 5
```

Second line is what you wanted to see printed.

Comment: Yes, it is calling from a class annotated `@Service` I tried also to call it from `@RestController` but no chance

Comment: Are you sure ? I made some sample demo and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I have a method like `@Service
public class MyServiceService {

    public void method(@Verify MyDto dto) {
        System.out.println("Method");
    }

}` and I call it from `@RestController` but it doesn't show me any message, which mean it not call the Aspect at all

Comment: Can you share the full example please? maybe I forgot something, or some configuration

Comment: Thank you for the full code, but It still not work with me, do you import something in pom.xml?

Comment: I accept the answer as it is full, but my problem is not resolved :)

Comment: In order for the Spring AOP to be working, you have to add, once again, from the spring documentation: The @AspectJ support can be enabled with XML- or Java-style configuration. In either case, you also need to ensure that AspectJ’s aspectjweaver.jar library is on the classpath of your application (version 1.8 or later). This library is available in the lib directory of an AspectJ distribution or from the Maven Central repository